# How to apply xText (grammar) file to the file loading in Eclipse RCP product

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtext

I am new to xText framework and want to apply the `.xText`(grammar) file to ie. `.myJava` file. Assuming that `.myJava` is the DSL extension and I am loading this file in Eclipse RCP product.

I couldn't find any clue how to integrate xText to RCP product.

Help with some examples is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "applying a grammar file to a source file"? Xtext can be added to an RCP product as any other plug-in/feature; what are you exactly struggling with?

Comment: Do you mean adding xText plugin in RCP product, will all my grammar be applied to file like .myJava ? I looked at xText example where there were two projects created. One is of plugin containing .xtext and another was UI. When compiling that xText ,i could the see syntax was highlighted. So I want similar implementation in RCP product rather than creating and opening .myJava file from UI plugin. For ie. In Eclipse , if i create any java file , some xText might have applied which results in syntax coloring and highlighting.

Comment: if you install the plugins + dependencies to the rcp you can simply use then. thus the question: what do you mean by integrate

Comment: Integrate means using xText plugin in any RCP product. When I open any file ie (. myJava) from RCP product's menu ie. Open > File > test.myJava , grammar from xText plugin should be applied to test.myJava and some syntax should be highlighted as mentioned in .xText file.

Comment: So, as we said if you install the Xtext plug-ins in an Eclipse-based application (or bundle them in your RCP product) then support for your language should be added. Did you try it? If it doesn't work could you tell us the steps you've followed so that we can try to spot the mistake and help you?